# Getting a username and uploading files

Tags: django, file, uploading

I'm using Django to upload files from a user.

When a user uploads a file, I need to grab their username as well, and add it to the model.

Initially, I was doing a hidden value of their username, but that can easily be changed (I'm looking at you, inspect element!)

So, I tried setting an initial value as I've read on here already.

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = {'uploader': request.user.username}
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial=username)
```

However, I keep getting an error returned that the uploader field wasn't set.
This is my form:

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=55)
    uploader = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), max_length=25)
    description = forms.TextInput()
    image = forms.ImageField()
    file = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Packs
        fields = ('title', 'uploader', 'description', 'image', 'file')
```

Comment: You should set the initial fields for handling `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to send the username at all. You already have access to it in `request.user.username`, as your own code demonstrates. If you can get it from there in the GET stage, you can do it just as well in the POST stage.